# prepairing an raw disk image to be readable/mountable crossplatform

Tags: disk-image, cross-platform

Does anyone know of an easy way to prepare a raw disk image to be accessible across platforms?

Sometimes I do data transfers for people and there are times when I just want to supply an image of the whole disk to the person just in case there is something missed in the transfer.

I was thinking of using clonezilla to create a raw image and then some how converting that to some kind of readable file container.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is **technically proficient**, a full disk image can be opened using the right tool. For example, an [image made using dd can be mounted under Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293646/convert-dd-image-file-to-iso). Certainly, supplying the user with a disk image is good service, because it allows *you* to go back and recover data that might have been missed, even if the *user* cannot access it, and I commend you for wanting to provide it!

**However:** an exact image of a disk would contain *each partition in its own file system (FS)*. For example, the Linux partition is likely using the *ext4* FS, which is not natively accessible from Windows (likely using *NTFS*). Though there are [third-party tools](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-read-ext4-in-windows-10) for Windows users to access *ext4* partitions, those I've tried have left some things to be desired.

In summary, if the drive is from the user's own PC, a disk image made with dd should be readable by them, or you could use other imaging software, such as Macrium Reflect, which runs on Windows and from a Rescue Environment on USB, to make the image, which can then be mounted using Reflect on the user's Windows OS PC. However, if the drive is from a different user, then the image might not be *directly* useful.

Comment: Thank you for the response I was hoping there was a way to convert a disk image to some kind of container archive  so someone without knowledge could open it like a zip file and seee its contents.

Comment: @trinsic, your idea of providing a user with a full image is *still* commendable! Even if some users cannot immediately access data, it allows them to give the image to someone who *could* try to recover data. The only downside might be providing media to store a large image.